# Geolocation API doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying few examples and none of them seems to work at all. 
Chrome and Firefox both ask me for permissions, but once i give them the rights nothing happens.

I used the example from http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation 
too, but doesn't work either.

What could be the problem , guys ?

Comment: Maybe your machine doesn't have the necessary hardware? Are you seeing any messages? Are you allowing your browser to reveal the location data? What browser are you using?

Comment: i just used and works and show my location, i'm using firefox 20.0.1 and Chrome 26.
this will to show a result with:
    Latitude:  ******
    Longitude: *****

Comment: What problem you are facing? Because its working in my browser..

Comment: I tried on Chrome (last version) and Firefox (last version) , both ask me for permissions but when i give 'em nothing happens. What hardware are you talking about , that i might not have

Comment: did you try the link from w3schools and it didn't work? you only need at least an internet connection to detect your location via navigator api.
try to open the console and check errors.

Comment: Yes, i tried w3schools - it asks me for permission to track my location , but when i allow it, nothing happens ( i mean it doesn't show me my location )

Comment: And by the way, i tried this on my laptop, and everything there is fine. So the problem seems to be only with my Desktop PC.